# Typescript: Property 'leave' does not exist on type 'Socket'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I want to leave a room in socket.io with socket.leave("roomname"). Typescript claims that

> "Property 'leave' does not exist on type 'Socket'"

.

Here is my code:

```js
import io from "socket.io-client";
// leave chat
export async function leaveChat(conversationId){
  const socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = io(process.env.SERVER_URL);
  socket.leave(`chat@${conversationId}`);
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure there is a leave method at all?

Comment: Nenroz said there is not, he is right. It's just in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leave` is function of `on` callback :

```js
import io from "socket.io-client";

export async function leaveChat(conversationId){
  const socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = io(process.env.SERVER_URL);
  socket.on('connection', s => {
    s.leave(`chat@${conversationId}`);
  });
}
```

You can check the documentation about it : https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-leave-room-callback

Comment: Ok thanks! So In the front end, I must emit a "leaveChat" event, and the server will kill the room thanks to socket.leave? I need to make sure a socket connection is killed both in client and server for performance issues. Or does socket IO automatically kill the room on both side if a user leave the page (not the website, just another page from the website)?

Comment: The `leave` function will remove the client from specified room, what you want to do next is to emit something, e.g. : `socket.to('room').emit(...);`